# how to cache a HttpPost request with image(s) in disk?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, http-post

I have a class named `Request` which implements `Serializable`, so that I can do things like below to save my entire `Request` object to disk

```
File file = new File(dir, request.name);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(request);
oos.close();
```

everything works fine if I didn't have image(s) in my request. image(s) are picked from disk, but I  don't want to store the path(s) since there might be chances where user delete/move the image(s).

I know that I can do things like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
image = baos.toByteArray();
```

and store `image` as `byte[]` or

```
String temp = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

as `String` in my `Request`.

but by doing so meaning I need to that for each individual image in the `Request`, and that would take a several seconds or even longer depending on how many images in the `Request` because I always need to convert `Bitmap` to `String` or `byte[]`. I was thinking to use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) to store my images, but then I realized I don't know how to include `Bitmap` in `MultipartEntity`. I currently use `ByteArrayBody`. not sure if there's a better way to achieve this?

Basically, I want a way to store the image(s) in the `Request` to disk, retrieve the `Request` at later point, then be able to do HttpPost....faster. doing `ByteArrayOutputStream` makes my app running slow

Answer (score 0):

Check Volley framework ;

[Volley framework sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html)